# basicaly i want this code to go to the number i choose like num 1 add only num 2 sub but it runs both regardless what number i put in

Tags: python, calculator

i tried everything shoould i add something in between or what i used to work with c++
so i dont know what to do

```
print("1   add")
print("2   sub")
print("3   mult")
print("4   div")
start = int(input("please choose what u want: "))

if start == "1":
    print("enter  your first number")
choose = float(input("please enter your first number: "))
chose = float(input("please enter your second number: "))
print("your answer is ", (choose + chose))

if start == "2":
    print("enter  your first number")
choose = float(input("please enter your first number: "))
chose = float(input("please enter your second number: "))
print("your answer is ", (choose - chose))
```

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming? In particular the section that tasks about how code is *indented*?

Comment: If you convert the input to `int`, you should not be surprised that it doesn't match a string value. If you don't put things in the `if` block, they get executed regardless. Same is true in C++ on both points, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have an **indentation** problem, as well as **condition** one.

Every **input** from the **console** is treated as a **string**.

You converted that input to **int** and then checked against the **string**, it isn't equal.

The right one would be:

```
start = input("please choose what u want: ")

if start == "1":
```

or

```
start = int(input("please choose what u want: "))

if start == 1:
```

Also, make sure to indent the code:

```
if start == "2":
    print("enter  your first number")
    choose = float(input("please enter your first number: "))
    chose = float(input("please enter your second number: "))
    print("your answer is ", (choose - chose))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your code inside the `if` statement like this:

```
start = int(input("please choose what u want: "))

if start == 1:
  print("enter  your first number")
  choose = float(input("please enter 
your first number: "))
  chose = float(input("please enter 
your second number: "))
  print("your answer is ", ( 
choose+chose))

if start == 2:

  print("enter  your first number")
  choose = float(input("please enter  
your first number: "))
  chose = float(input("please enter 
your second number: "))
  print("your answer is ", (choose - 
chose))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
print("1   add")
print("2   sub")
print("3   mult")
print("4   div")
start = int(input("please choose what u want: "))

if start == 1:
    print("enter  your first number")
    choose = float(input("please enter your first number: "))
    chose = float(input("please enter your second number: "))
    print("your answer is ", (choose + chose))

elif start == 2:
    print("enter  your first number")
    choose = float(input("please enter your first number: "))
    chose = float(input("please enter your second number: "))
    print("your answer is ", (choose - chose))
```

The data you get from the user is integer, but the type you are querying is string. Your code is not working due to data type mismatch. I have specified the correct code above.

Comment: What was it that you changed to fix the problem, and why?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).